# Process exited with return value 255, w/pointers to structures

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have some functions that should allow me to manage a structure which was allocated dynamically. The allocation of the memory and the input of data in those is no real problem, though my program stops when it reaches a certain line of code: (No warning or problems detected)

```
if(codeV == p_vendite[ctrl_j].p_venditore[ctrl_i].codVenditore)
```

This line is in the function called `VenditeProdotto(Vendite *p_vendite)`.

Here's the important part of the code (defining structures)

```
typedef struct _Venditore {
  int codVenditore;
  int codProdotto;
  int qty;
} Venditore;

typedef struct _Vendite{
  int mmGG;
  Venditore *p_venditore;
} Vendite;

void AggiungiVendita (Vendite *p_vendite);
void VenditeProdotto(Vendite *p_vendite);
void VenditeVenditore(Vendite *p_vendite);
...
```

Here's `main()`:

```
int main() {
  int check, i, count, flag, choice;
  Vendite *p_Vendite;
  ...
  ...
  p_Vendite = (Vendite*) calloc(numVenditori,sizeof(Vendite));
  ...
  ...
  p_Vendite->p_venditore = (Venditore*)calloc(numVenditori,sizeof(Venditore));

/*menu*/

  flag = TRUE;
  do{
    choice = menu();
    switch (choice) {
      case 1 : AggiungiVendita(p_Vendite); break;
      ...
      case 3 : VenditeProdotto(p_Vendite); break;
      case 4 : VenditeVenditore(p_Vendite); break;
      ...
    }

  } while (flag == TRUE);

  return 0;
}
```

And here are the functions:

```
void AggiungiVendita (Vendite *p_vendite) {
  int flag, check, answer;
  i = 0;
  do{

    /*input of struct - codVenditore,codProdotto,qty*/
    ...
    check = scanf("%d", &(p_vendite[j].p_venditore[i].codVenditore));
    ...

    /*input*/
    check = scanf("%d", &(p_vendite[j].p_venditore[i].codProdotto) );
    ...
    /*controllo sull'input*/
    check = scanf("%d", &(p_vendite[j].p_venditore[i].qty) );
    ...
    ...
    //asking to redo or quit
  } while(flag == TRUE && i < numVenditori);

  return;
}

int menu() {
  //just a standard menu, no problem here
  ...
  return choice;
}

void VenditeProdotto(Vendite *p_vendite) {
  int check = 0, codeP = 0, ctrl_i = 0, ctrl_j = 0; //ctrl_i,ctrl_j are increasing variables and I use them to search among the structures

  ...//input, continues after
```

Where I find the debug error: (line 3 after this)

```
  for(ctrl_j = 0; ctrl_j < numVendite; ctrl_j++) {

    for(ctrl_i = 0; ctrl_i < numVenditori; ctrl_i++) {
      if (codeP == p_vendite[ctrl_j].p_venditore[ctrl_i].codProdotto)
        printf("\nSeller %d, quantity sold: %d in day %d", p_vendite[ctrl_j].p_venditore[ctrl_i].codVenditore, p_vendite[ctrl_j].p_venditore[ctrl_i].qty, ctrl_j+1);
      else 
        continue;
    }

  }

  return;
}
```

Basically I don't know if it's really legit to use the first line of code that I've talked about, with `.` instead of `->`, but if I try to change the syntax I get detected errors. Any ideas?

At first I thought about something like `(p_vendite+ctrl_j)->(p_venditore+ctrl_i)->codProdotto`, since it's a pointer but it doesn't seem working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of obvious bugs:

### Allocation of `Vendite`

You're allocating `numVenditori` elements for `p_Vendite`, but later on you are iterating `numVendite` times over the same pointer:

> ```
> p_Vendite = (Vendite*) calloc(numVenditori,sizeof(Vendite));
>
> ...
>
> for(ctrl_j = 0; ctrl_j < numVendite; ctrl_j++) {
>   for(ctrl_i = 0; ctrl_i < numVenditori; ctrl_i++) {
>     if (codeP == p_vendite[ctrl_j].p_venditore[ctrl_i].codProdotto)
> ```

The allocation should read:

```
p_Vendite = (Vendite*) calloc(numVendite,sizeof(Vendite));
```

or as I would prefer it:

```
p_Vendite = calloc (numVendite, sizeof *p_Vendite);
```

### Allocation of `Venditore`

> ```
> p_Vendite->p_venditore = (Venditore*)calloc(numVenditori,sizeof(Venditore));
> ```

You're only allocating the `p_venditore` element for **one** of your `Vendite` structs. You need to allocate all of them in a loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < numVendite; j++) {
  p_Vendite[j].p_venditore = (Venditore*)calloc(numVenditori,sizeof(Venditore));
  // And check for allocation errors
}
```